# gdal2tiles Can Not Open Input File

Tags: error, gdal2tiles, vrt

I am using gdal2tiles to convert a vrt to tiles but getting the following message:

> ERROR 4: 'Depth (Max).vrt' not recognized as a supported file format.
>   Usage: [.....]
>   gdal2tiles.py: error: It is not possible to open the input file 'Depth (Max).vrt'

Here's my code located in a batch file:

```
@python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal2tiles.py" -s EPSG:2278 -z 12 -w none -k "Depth <Max>.vrt" depth_max
```

I am running this from the OSGeo4W Shell. I had this working at one point so I suspect it is just a syntax problem with the quotes?

Comment: Try to avoid brackets and blanks in the filename, and maybe add the full path to the file.

Comment: @AndreJ Adding the full path does not help. And I would prefer not to change the filename, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake. The file name uses "( )" but I used "< >" in my batch file (not intentionally). I was previously typing it directly into the cmd window where "( )" shows up as "< >", so it was a simple error.